# ¿Como ingresar el usuario y contraseña de un proxy en Firefox?

Tags: java, selenium, proxy

**Hola.**

Actualmente puedo cargar una **Proxy HTTPS** pero el problema que esta **proxy** tiene una un **usuario** y **contraseña** para poder usarse y no encuentro la forma de ingresar estos datos, desde **Selenium** sin tener que recurrir a la **clase Robot**. No puedo usar la **clase Robot** y simplemente escribir y usar los datos ya que voy hacer que el **Firefox** trabaje en **modo Headless**.

Mi código actual es cargar al **WebDriver** un **FirefoxOptions** el cual tiene establecido un perfil con la **proxy** a ingresar:

```
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", ip);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", puerto);
```

Esta **configuración del pefil** me permite cargar la proxy correctamente, pero no encuentro como cargar el **usuario** y **contraseña** también desde el perfil. Intente hacerlo así:

```
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl", usuario+":"+clave+"@"+ip);
profile.setPreference("network.proxy.ssl_port", puerto);
```

Y la **proxy** se cargo pero no correctamente porque no me pidió **usuario** y **contraseña** porque así no acepta que escriba la **direccion IP**. Y tampoco me dejo navegar. Lo que necesito es simplemente cargar el usuario y contraseña desde **Selenium**.

**Gracias** y espero su apoyo-

Comment: ¿Has probado a tratarlo como un alert?

Comment: Puede que te falte 'https://' en el proxy.ssl, delante del usuario.